# RPC command to list current nodes

Tags: parity, rpc, node-discovery

I am using Parity and I want to see a list of the IP addresses of every node my node is talking to.  I am sure I have done this before but I can't remember how.  Please share the curl/RPC command to do this.

This does NOT work:

```
$ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"admin.peers","params":[],"id":83}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32601,"message":"Method not found"},"id":83}
```

The Parity search gives no answer with this search: `https://wiki.parity.io/index.html?q=admin.peers`

`parity_netPeers` also does not work.  This lists many peers that I am not connected to.  I only want the list of the (1) node I am connected to.